# Changing wheel size when adding ebike kit to tricycle

Tags: wheels, tricycle, electric-bike

I have a 20" wheel trike I plan to motorize. Can I add a 24" or 26" Hub front wheel motor and can I mix the front and rear tire sizes?

What are the consequences for stability and cornering?

I am new to e-biking and would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Presumably you'd have to make sure it fit first.

Comment: Is the trike a tadpole or delta? One or two front wheels?

Comment: A trike with 20" wheels could have many different configurations, from high quality bike wheels to crummy kiddie trike wheels twisting on a rod with no real bearings.  And if you increase the front wheel size without changing the others there's no telling what it would do to the comfort and fit of the trike.  Finally, trikes are some of the most unstable and rollover-prone vehicles made.

Comment: Changed title to be more appropos.

Comment: Related and perhaps a duplicate: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/20988/11160

Comment: You can rebuild your wheel wiht the electric motor hub inside a 20" rim, provided its not too big.  However the spokes will need to be replaced with shorter ones, and there's a good chance the motor will put the pokes at silly angles.     Can you give us a photo of your bike please ?

Comment: @DanielRHicks - long wheelbase recumbents trikes (esp tadpoles) might be the counterexample for a stable, highspeed trike. But it's highly unlikely that the OP has a recumbent and more likely they're talking about Huffy BSO trike. Let's see what the response is.

Comment: @Criggie - A large hub in a small wheel is a recipe for broken spokes and other wheel problems.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer addresses "stability and cornering"*

If you do motorise your trike with a hub motor, it will gain 2-5 kilograms in the middle of the wheel.  This is "unsprung weight"  Depending on the battery number, size and chemistry you will also add 0.5-10 kilograms of storage somewhere on the frame.

So your bike will get heavier by ~3-15 kilos.  This is balanced out by the assistance provided by the motor as long as you have power, for regular straight-ahead riding.

A hub motor in a regular bike's front wheel aggravates any conditions.  If you ride in the wet or on damp leaves, its more likely to slide out under you.   I've never ridden a rear-hub motor, but I imagine its similar, and powering through any corners is a bad idea.

The motor is also unsprung weight, in vehicle terms that's the weight that is always pressing on the road with no suspension.  Increased weight makes jumps much harder, and increases the impact of anything like potholes and road debris.

A test you can do is to get some weights that are about as heavy as the kit you want to fit, and got for a ride with these weights on your bike.  Bags or plastic bottles of water might be safest.  This will show you about how it will feel if the battery is flat.

---

Personal story - I had an electrified MTB for a while, and it was capable of 40+ km/h with pedalling.  I had multiple instances of cars seeing me in the distance and pulling out without anticipating my speed.

Now I have a road bike and can get to similar speeds without the boost, and because I look faster then cars have been less likely to pull out.

I also found it was too easy to take corners at speed.  Several times I turned 90 degrees and found myself halfway across the car lane, because I was riding to preserve my momentum.  Once I was clear on the wrong side of the road, and fortunately only good luck meant no cars were oncoming.

Summary - ebikes are a gateway drug into riding your bike more.  They're a sop to the conscience for those who want to but can't quite.... as such they do have a place in cycling.

---

Changing the wheel size is well covered in other questions, like:

- [Kid's bike - Can I put 20" wheel on a frame that was meant for 18" wheels?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/39056/kids-bike-can-i-put-20-wheel-on-a-frame-that-was-meant-for-18-wheels)
- [Can I change my 28" wheels for 24"?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30428/can-i-change-my-28-wheels-for-24)
- [Can I run a 700c/28"/29er wheel & tire on a 650B full-suspension mountain bike frame?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/37892/can-i-run-a-700c-28-29er-wheel-tire-on-a-650b-full-suspension-mountain-bike-f)
- [Can I swap a 29er fork inplace of a 27.5 if I maintain close to the same axle to crown length?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30904/can-i-swap-a-29er-fork-inplace-of-a-27-5-if-i-maintain-close-to-the-same-axle-to)

Short summery is "maybe" if it fits without rubbing, but brakes may be an issue.  Geometry of the bike is also changed in various ways.  I'd expect your forks to be too short for a larger wheel, so you're up for replacing them too, if the trike has forks.

Comment: p.s. I think some of the stability concerns in the OP's question were regarding what happens when a bigger 24" wheel is put onto a 20" trike, not just about electrification.

Comment: @RoboKaren yeah good spotting - I've listed out some of the dupes for that bit of the question.  Some are opposites, but the ideas are related.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't just plop a larger front-wheel hub motor into a bike or trike willy-nilly. There are various considerations including wheelsize and drop-out width. For example, although it might be deadly obvious, you can't put a 100mm front ehub wheel in the rear of a tadpole because: 1) it will likely be the wrong dropout width; 2) it won't have a freehub for your chain (if applicable).

Once you got that sorted out, changing the size of the front wheel in a delta or rear wheel in a tadpole depends on the frame.  In most cases, you won't have enough **frame or fork clearance** to put in a larger wheel. Furthermore, you'll also run into problems with your brakes (unless you have disc brakes) as the brake bosses will be in the wrong place. Your rim and associated tires might be too thick for the frame. Finally, you'll also change the angle at which the seat sits in relation to the handlebars. So in general, thinking about changing wheel size is a Bad Idea® because it won't fit, let alone stability issues.

[image]

Rather than using whatever wheel you found, it's so much easier to just build-up the right 20" ebike wheel. That way you can get the right drop-out width, rim width, and add options for disc brakes or a freehub, if applicable. You'd start with the appropriate sized e-hub -- so a rear wheel (135mm dropout) ehub for the rear of a tadpole -- or 100mm for front wheel of a delta. This assumes your bike's dropouts or forks are designed for those widths.

There are many places will build you the exact type of  20" wheel that you need. We're not a shopping recommendation site but Lunacycle.com is a good first place to browse to get a sense of what options you might have.

<sub>If I've convinced you changing wheel sizes is a bad idea but you already have the wheel, as @Criggie notes, you could have the hub motor of the wheel rebuilt using your existing rims. However, generally ehubs for smaller wheels are wound different (have a different rpm/V) than those for bigger wheels, so you may have more starting torque but a lower top speed. And many hub motors will not physically fit into a 20" wheels -- really only the smaller geared ones work.</sub>

Note that because of the complexities of tricycles (and recumbents), many people use mid-drive motors (like the Bafang mid-drive) to instead motorize the crank.

Comment: Also, you can't fit most front wheel motors to a tadpole trike, as the dropout spacing is wrong at the back and the front is single side mount. Which is why that is the first mod required to the question before anyone can write a useful answer.

Comment: Because they asked " 24" or 26" Hub front wheel motor"

Comment: I assume that's what they found on a cheap e-bike kit site. Edited answer to clarify why they should reconsider. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

As said you could get a 24” wheel and have the hub taken out and laced into your existing front wheel. If going down this route make sure the e-bike controller can be set for a 20” wheel otherwise the speedometer might not display the wrong speed and it MIGHT affect the pedal assist ratios.
I’m not getting what issue is about the xtra hub and battery weight as it a bit like saying Fred at 90kg will be OK on it but as soon as Mike gets on it at 95Kg there going to be additional stability issues. There might be but these are manageable.
I have fitted as 26 front wheel e-bike kit on my 26” wheeled trike that has a thumb throttle limited to 4mph and I found that when crossing inclines the trike wants to run to the downhill side but with a little throttle the front wheel pulls the trike in the direction it’s steered. Yes it will wheel spin on wet grass but you can change the power ratios from 5 settings to 9, thus lowering the power asist percentage delivered to the front wheel.
You’ll find you’ll probably need to mount the battery in front of the rear basket or actually in it is mounting it typically on the down tube may well restrict you stepping through.
Key thing to know about tradition trikes is you cannot take bends at high speed unless you employ some serious leaning into the bend. I would take a bend at no more than 5mph and going across inclines is not advised but can’t always be avoided so leaning towards up hill is essential whereas on a bike you automatically remain upright.
Shop around and find a supplier that does a 20” wheel as you can get them as small as 16”. Brompton bike have small wheels so there you go.

Comment: It seems you're talking about rebuilding the existing wheel with a power hub instead of changing the wheel size.  I'm not sure that actually answers the question that was asked.  Also, this is a big wall of text and could use being trimmed or broken into paragraphs (or both).

Comment: They wanted know about fitting a larger wheel which they can’t so gave them an alternative solution to the problem. 
Sorry about the lack of paragraphs but I only manage a GCSE grade 5 in English.